# Calling a Function from a String in C

Tags: c

In C, how to do you call a function from just having its name as a string?  I have this:

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    char* events[] = {
        "test",
        "test2"
    };

    int i = 0;
    for (; i < 2; ++i){
        char* event = events[i];
        // call function with name of "event"
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it, but there's not much built-in to help out.

```
typedef struct { 
    char *event_name;
    void (*handler)();
} event_handler;
```

then search through an array (or whatever) of `event_handler`s, and when you find the right name, call the associated function.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more, I'm not exactly sure how this would be done.

Answer (score 4):

There is no standard way to do this. In practice you can sometimes do it using platform specific things (such as `dlopen` on *nix), but it's just not a very good idea. If you really want to do something like this, you should be using a reflective language.

Set up a table of structs of strings and function pointers to use as a lookup for your function.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call a function that was linked in using the dynamic linker (or if your program was compiled with `-rdynamic`) you can use `dlsym()` to get the address of a function pointer and call that.

If you'd like to invoke a function based on the contents of a given string, you can use the above, or you can wrap a constant string with a function pointer inside of a structure and invoke each.

Comment: I was bored and wrote it: http://codepad.org/3BRapq7T (unfortunately codepad doesn't seem to offer the library needed)

Comment: @Martin: dlopen() and family have been around before: Unix adopted them and POSIX standardized them. A similar facility exists on a couple of non-POSIX systems, like Win32, using `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`.

Answer (score 0):

since your array only has 2 items... my noob way =)

```
if ( strcmp(event, "function1") == 0 ) {
  function1();
} else if { strcmp(event, "function2") == 0 ) {
  function2();
}
```

Comment: Strings in C don't compare like that.

Comment: The straightforward way to compare strings in C is with `strcmp()`: `if (strcmp(event, "function1") == 0) { function1(); }`

Comment: Just a btw, `strcmp` return 0 when the strings match, not the other way.

Answer (score 0):

Compare the input string against known function names.

If string X... call function X